# Allocating 2 times more memory to my stack (only if needed) C

Tags: c, memory-management, stack

I have a code in C language with a stack that has defined size of 3 and i need the program to be able to allocate 2x more size if its needed. The code now looks like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    char *items;
    int max;
    int count;
};

struct stack *
stack_init(int max)
{
    struct stack *s = (struct stack *) malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    s->items = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * max);
    s->max = max;
    s->count = 0;

    return s;
}

void
stack_destroy(struct stack *s)
{

    free(s->items);
    free(s);
}

int
stack_isempty(struct stack *s)
{

    return 0 == s->count;
}

int
stack_push(struct stack *s, char item)
{

    if (s->count >= s->max)
        return -1;

    s->items[s->count] = item;
    ++(s->count);

    return 0;
}

int
stack_pop(struct stack *s, char *item)
{

    if (s->count <= 0)
        return -1;

    --(s->count);
    *item = s->items[s->count];

    return 0;
}

void
main(void)
{

    struct stack *s = stack_init(3);

    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    printf("Error pushu? %d\n", stack_push(s, 'A'));
    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    printf("error pushu? %d\n", stack_push(s, 'B'));
    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    printf("error pushu? %d\n", stack_push(s, 'C'));
    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    char ch;

    printf("error popu? %d\n", stack_pop(s, &ch));
    printf("Pop returned (if returned): %c\n", ch);
    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    printf("error popu? %d\n", stack_pop(s, &ch));
    printf("Pop returned (if returned): %c\n", ch);
    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    printf("error popu? %d\n", stack_pop(s, &ch));
    printf("Pop returned (if returned): %c\n", ch);
    printf("free? %d\n\n", stack_isempty(s));

    stack_destroy(s);
}
```

If somebody can help.

Comment: Now you need to format it to make it readable for humans.

Comment: Are you looking for the [realloc](https://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) function? Because it is unclear what your specific problem is. You have described what you want to do but have not asked a question or explained what specific problem prevents you from progressing.

Comment: In your push function, where you check whether the stack is full... if it is, just reallocate instead of returning an error code (which you can still do if it fails).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very sure is this what you want?

```
int
stack_push(struct stack *s, char item)
{
        int max = 0;

        if (s->count >= s->max){
                max = s->max * 2;
                s->items = (char*)realloc(s->items, sizeof(char)*max);
                if(NULL==s->items){
                        return -1;
                }
                s->max = max;
        }

        s->items[s->count] = item;
        ++(s->count);

        return 0;
}
```